# Question on Fulton's algebraic curve, Chapter 1.7

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Chapter 1.7, corollary 4 states:
Let $k$ be algebraically closed, $I$ be an ideal of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$. Then $V(I)$ is a finite set if and only if $k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $k$.

Proof of corollary 4 uses a result from the previous exercise: Let $P_1,...,P_r$ be distinct points in $\mathbb A^n(k)$, not in an algebraic set $V$, then there are polynomials $F_1,...,F_r ∈ I(V)$ such that $F_i(P_j ) = 0$
if $i\neq j$ and $F_i(P_i) = 1.$

However, in the proof, he picks $P_1,...,P_r \in V(I)$, and finally shows that $r \leq$ dim $k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$. I think we should pick $P_1,...,P_r \notin V(I)$ to use the previous result, but I don't know how to complete this proof by using this result. If this proof is wrong, is there another proof of this corollary? Here is the proof of this part in the book:

Let $P_1,...,P_r ∈ V(I)$. Choose $F_1,...,F_r ∈ k[X_1,...,X_n]$ such that $F_i(P_j) = 0$ if
$i \neq j$, and $F_i(P_i) = 1$ (Problem 1.17); let $\overline F_i$ be the $I$-residue of $F_i$. If $\sum_{i=1}^{r} λ_i \overline F_i = 0, λ_i ∈ k$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{r}λ_iF_i ∈ I$, so $λ_j = (\sum_{i=1}^{r} λ_iF_i)(P_j) = 0$. Thus the $F_i$ are linearly independent over
$k$, so $r ≤ dim_k(k[X_1,..., X_n]/I)$.

Comment: Why do you think we should pick $P_i\notin V(I)$? The proof works fine as is.

Comment: @KReiser the condition in previous exercise is '$P_1,...,P_r∉V(I)$', so only with this condition we can have $F_1,...,F_r$.

Comment: Take the empty set as the set that the $P_i$ aren't in. (The $V$ from the previous exercise isn't necessarily the same $V$ as in this exercise.)

Comment: wait, in your first line: it should be $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$ is a finite vector space?

Comment: @KReiser Oh... Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sisi yeah, already fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any $j$, $V=\{P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_{j-1}, P_{j+1}, \cdots, P_r\}$ is Zariski closed (as a union of closed subsets i.e. singletons), and $P_j$ is not in it. By the "previous exercise", there exists $F_j\in I(V)$ that vanishes at $V$ and $F_j(P_j)=1$. Indeed, it's an easy exercise to produce $F_j$ in this context than to establish the exercise first.

In fact, this produces a proof of the exercise: $V':=V\cup\{P_1, \cdots, P_{j-1}, P_{j+1}, \cdots, P_r\}$ is Zariski closed, hence there must be a polynomial that vanishes on all of $V$ and $\{P_i\}_{i\not=j}$ but not $P_j$, for otherwise, $P_j$ will be forced in the Zariski closure of $V'$ which is already closed.

Or as already commented by KReiser, to directly apply the exercise, just consider $V=V(k[x_1, \cdots,x_n])=\emptyset$, then we can find all of $F_1, \cdots, F_n$ simultaneously.

This proves that if $k[x_1, \cdots, x_n]/I$ is of finite dimension over $k$, then $V(I)$ is finite, but not the other direction.